# Using Async/Await with node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using node-postgres to query my database and would like to know how to use async/await and handle errors correctly

An example of my use is here with a very simple query

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

let config;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
  config = { connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL, ssl: true };
} else {
  config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    database: 'mydatabase',
  };
}

const pool = new Pool(config);

async function getAllUsers() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query('select * FROM users');
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  return response.rows;
}
```

Then in my `routes.js` I have

```
app.get('/all_users', async (req, res) => {
  const users = await queries.getAllUsers();
  console.log(users); // returns all users fine
});
```

This is my understanding so far, but i don't think I am approaching this correctly as when it comes to errors my app will freeze and throw `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. So if I provide an incorrect table for example

```
async function getAllUsers() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query('select * FROM notable');
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  return response.rows;
}

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: relation "notable" does not exist
```

The app will crash after 30 seconds and I have not handled this error gracefully. What am I missing?

Comment: For handling errors you might want to look at await-to-js which provides cleaner syntax for error handling when working with promises

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When an `async` function or `Promise` throws an uncaught error, or when the *catcher also* throws, such as with your

```
throw error;
```

this means that the *caller* of the function will be faced with a rejected Promise to deal with. If you're using `await` in the caller, then you'll also have to use `try/catch` in the caller in order to catch the errors properly:

```
app.get('/all_users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await queries.getAllUsers();
    console.log(users);
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Another way to resolve the error without having to use `try/catch` in the consumer would be not to `throw` the error in your `catch`:

```
async function getAllUsers() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query('select * FROM users');
    return response.rows;
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
    // do not throw anything
  }
}
```

but this will make it harder for the consumer to know when there was an error.

In this particular case, the `async`/`await`/`try`/`catch` constructions add a lot of syntax noise without much benefit IMO - for the moment, you might consider using plain Promises instead:

```
const getAllUsers = () => pool.query('select * FROM users')
  .then(response => response.rows);

// and:
app.get('/all_users', (req, res) => {
  queries.getAllUsers()
    .then((users) => {
      console.log(users);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle errors
    });
});
```

`async` and `await` shines when you have a few `.then`s that you'd like to look flatter in your code. If there's only one `.then`, IMO there's not much benefit to transforming it into `async`/`await` syntax. Of course, it's up to you.

Comment: In addition to the above, a common option is to use a server package or middleware that automatically catches unhanded errors and just turns them into HTTP 500s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I am using async/await unnecessarily, valid point raised. Also thank you for clearing up that i should be handling the error from the caller side to (simple thing i missed there)

Comment: It's common to have a single query executor function which has the try catch and call that elsewhere, so you don't have to repeat it everywhere. See https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure